# How to open vim inside a bash script?

Tags: bash, vim

Hey how can I open vim inside a script?
I need to grade coding assignments and wrote a script to open code and note files, but vim does not open.
The script is essentially a fancier version of this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$student_files" | while read student do
   vim -o $student
done

#each "$student" looks like: "file1 file2 [...] notes"
```

But vim complains about:

```bsh
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I could work around it?
Thanks in advance :)

<sub>**note:** I tried running vim in a script **without** a loop, which works, but I don't know why. I suppose its because I'm piping into while</sub>

Comment: Yes it's because you are piping to `while` ... `vim` is responding to the pipeline as well.

Comment: Is `$student_files` a variable containing newlines?

Comment: @bxm now I see it. the `-e` was missing. But the real script contains a `sed` command, so it works there.

Comment: Amended my answer to reflect this new info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the pipeline, standard input is redirected for the `while` loop; that includes any command that is launched from it, like `vim`.

As you always want to get input from the terminal there, you can just re-connect to the terminal, `/dev/tty`:

```
< /dev/tty vim -o "$student"
```

Alternatively, *stdin* could be saved to a file descriptor before going into the pipeline (`exec 6<&0`) and that passed to Vim (`<&6 vim -o ...`). (That would also handle the case where a "macro recording" of Vim commands is saved in a file and you wanted to automate Vim itself by piping the recorded input back into it.)

Or you could try to get rid of the pipeline completely, by first reading the entire file contents into a Bash array (`readarray`), and then using a simple `for` loop. This would consume more memory, but that shouldn't be a problem here as the limiting factor rather is how many Vim sessions you're willing to handle sequentially :-) Actually, you're not reading from a file here, but from variable contents (which as I understand have space-separated students on potentially multiple lines - the default `IFS` parsing will split those into individual students), so all you need to do is simple *word splitting* into a Bash array:

```
declare -a students=($student_files)
for student in "${students[@]}"
do
    vim -o "$student"
done
```

or completely skipping the intermediate array:

```
for student in $student_files
do
    vim -o "$student"
done
```

Comment: Thanks I really liked your explanation. :) reconnecting to the tty worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare -a student_array=()
while read line ; do student_array+=("$line") ; done < <(echo -e "$student_array")
for student in "${student_array[@]}" ; do
  vim -o $student
done
```

Comment: `eval` is not needed here (and is best avoided); rather, `$student` should be quoted. And in Bash 4 you can replace the `while` loop with `readarray`

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if `eval` was warranted (you are indeed correct, have removed), but I think if `$student` were quoted, it would not work. From the limited information given, I'm surmising the pseudo-array being used as input is newline delimited, with space separated items per line.  Quoting `$student` would try to open them as a single file.

Comment: I made some typos which became apparent in testing, edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
]# cat filelist 
fsc
out
]# vim -o $(<filelist)
2 files to edit
]#
```

...and in between I had these two files "fsc" and "out" *stacked* in vim.

I used `man vim` for once.

I had to give up my xterm window after I had tested your script. Even after `reset` the BS key would only do "^H". So I radically changed.

Comment: This opens the files of all students simultaneously, which is why I need the while loop to edit student by student.

Comment: OK...I started out by checking 'vim -o'. I think I see the point now, with ingo's last solution -- it's two-level. thanks!